# Read data id data from .txt file using vector c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, struct

Can I get id data from a txt file and show it using vector, and I want to make a loop if the entry data > 1.

This is the struct:

```
struct databrg{ 
    int id;
    char namabrg[10];
    int harga;
    int jumlahbrg;

}databrg;
```

This is the vector:

```
vector<string> explode(string const & s, char delim){ 
    vector<string> result;
    istringstream iss(s);
    for (string id; getline(iss, id, delim); ){
        result.push_back(id);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the entry data():

```
void entri_data(){ //proses entri data
   ofstream file ("stok.txt", ios::app); 

   char tambah;
   cout<<"Apakah anda ingin entri data ? (Y/N) "<<endl; 
    cin>>tambah;
    while(tambah == 'y'){
    cout<<"Jumlah data yang ingin dientri: ";cin>>n;
     // n is how much the data entry and if the data > 1 and will loop the entri data again ?
    cout<<"Data ke "; // i want to show the current entry data id from txt file using vector but i don't know how ?

    cout<<"Nama Barang: ";
    cin>>databrg.namabrg;
    cout<<"Harga Barang: ";
    cin>>databrg.harga;
    cout<<"Jumlah Barang: ";
    cin>>databrg.jumlahbrg; 
      if(file.is_open()){ 
        file << databrg.id <<" "<< databrg.namabrg <<" "<< databrg.harga << " "<< databrg.jumlahbrg << "\n";
        cout<<"Data Berhasil ditambahkan\n";
        file.clear();
      }else cout << "Tidak bisa membuka file\n"; 
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @Hariom i want to show the current entry data id from txt file using vector